# Blob Storage Images - Azure

Tags: blob, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I have some problems with images that I upload through my web api to a public container in my blob storage. The problem is that i need the image i uploaded through my api have to be browseable, i mean when put the public link in a browser you can see the image in the browser, but the actual behavior  is that when i put the link the image make a download of the image and doesnt show me nothing in the browser But when i Upload the image through the azure portal i can see the image as I want.... I have my container public and i dont know what else to do.... my code to upload a image is this:

```
    private readonly CloudBlobContainer blobContainer;

    public UploadBlobController()
    {
        var storageConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"];
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("messagesthredimages");
        blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
        blobContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UploadImagetoBlob")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadImagetoBlob()//string imagePath
    {
        try
        {
            var image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
            var imageBytes = image.GetBytes();
            var blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(image.FileName);
            blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "messagesthreadimages/" + image.ImageFormat;
            await blockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            return Ok(blockBlob.Uri.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

    }
```

Examples, I hope somebody can help me with this.

What I Want      => [Correct](https://profuturobotdevstorage.blob.core.windows.net/messagesthredimages/birthday25.gif)

What I dont Want => [Incorrect](https://profuturobotdevstorage.blob.core.windows.net/messagesthredimages/birthday27.gif)

Comment: do you have the azure storage desktop app?

Comment: Nop, the services is azure blob storage, but my app upload images to that storage

Comment: yes there is a desktop app that is handy to monitor the azure blob storage.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane yep throught the desktop y through the portal is ok.. The problem is when my web api method upload the image

Comment: well the app helped me debug several such issues. Anyways look at my answer, that should help you figure out your issue

Comment: any reason u have `"messagesthreadimages/"`?

Comment: Thank you, i will check... I didnt notice thst string in tje content type that was my error i will try and back to mark the answer if everything work ok

Comment: yeah i face the exact same issue when I had the wrong/no content type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same issue before. Browsers download a file when they do not know the format (file type). If you monitor the files with the desktop app (no sure where this option is in the portal), you will find the file types.

These file types are set based on the `blockBlob.Properties.ContentType` you are setting. You need to inspect and check what exactly `image.ImageFormat` returns. The browser would only display the image if the this value is set to something like `"image/jpeg"`. However since you are using `"messagesthreadimages/" + image.ImageFormat`, it might be setting something like `"messagesthreadimages/image/jpeg"`.

Answer (score 1):

As Neville said, you have some misunderstand when you call SetProperties method like blockBlob.Properties.ContentType.

Content-Type indicates the media type of the message content.

The image content type **allows standardized image files** to be included in messages. For more detail,you could refer to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527550(v=exchg.10).aspx).

```
image/g3fax [RFC1494]
image/gif [RFC1521]
image/ief (Image Exchange Format) [RFC1314]
image/jpeg [RFC1521]
image/tiff (Tag Image File Format) [RFC2301]
```

I read this [article](http://www.ojdevelops.com/2016/05/end-to-end-image-upload-with-azure.html) and it seems that you would customize the ContentType of image.
So, you could change code as below:

```
blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/" + image.ImageFormat;
```

Comment: generally getting the format includes the `"images/"` part